# Implicit Deny in calico global network policy?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, calico

I am puzzled about this behaviour of global network policies. Take the following.

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-dns-for-all-policy
spec:
  namespaceSelector: has(projectcalico.org/name) && projectcalico.org/name not in {"kube-system", "calico-system"}
  order: 0
  egress:
  # allow all namespaces to communicate to DNS pods
  - action: Allow
    protocol: UDP
    destination:
      ports:
      - 53
  ingress:
  - action: Allow
```

When i do a wget from one pod to another in a "test" namespace it can apparently resolve dns but doesn't return the package:

```
Resolving nginx-test (nginx-test)... 10.233.8.253
Connecting to nginx-test (nginx-test)|10.233.8.253|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
```

There is no other policy on the cluster, especially no default-deny policy. I also tested without namespaceSelector. Only when i add a second `Allow` Rule that matches *, or when i delete the whole policy i get a successful return.

Why is that? I would have expected that this policy has no effect on communication since there is no DENY rule present.

Answer (score 3):

Well turns out if there is at least one ingress/egress rule matching on a ressource calico automatically adds a default deny rule to ingress/egress.

> If no network policies apply to a pod, then all traffic to/from that pod is allowed.
> If one or more network policies apply to a pod containing ingress rules, then only the ingress traffic specifically allowed by those policies is allowed.
> If one or more network policies apply to a pod containing egress rules, then only the egress traffic specifically allowed by those policies is allowed.

https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/calico-network-policy